# What is TimerFired in AWS SimpleWorkflow

Tags: amazon-swf

I am running workflow on the AWS console. I saw there is a Event Type called "TimerFired" in the console. What does it do?

Answer (score 2):

[TimerFired](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_TimerFiredEventAttributes.html) event is generated when timer scheduled through [StartTimer](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/apireference/API_StartTimerDecisionAttributes.html) decision fires. It also causes a new decision being scheduled to give decider chance to handle the timer event.